# Can I reduce the registration of a generic class?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I created an interface with a class:

```
public interface IBackgroundSubscriber<T>
{
    ...
}

public class BackgroundSubscriber<T> : IBackgroundSubscriber<T>
{
    ...
}
```

Then I wanted to register it with the `Unity` IoC container:

```
private void RegisterServicesAndViews()
{
    _container.RegisterType<IBackgroundSubscriber<TypeA>, BackgroundSubscriber<TypeA>>();
    _container.RegisterType<IBackgroundSubscriber<TypeB>, BackgroundSubscriber<TypeB>>();
}
```

And then run it:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    _container.Resolve<IBackgroundSubscriber<TypeA>>();
    _container.Resolve<IBackgroundSubscriber<TypeB>>();

    ... 
}
```

But now it looks like I have to specify the `TypeA` and `TypeB` a lot (3 times).
Can I make this even smarter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
_container.RegisterType(typeof(IBackgroundSubscriber<>),
                        typeof(BackgroundSubscriber<>));
```

See [Registering Type Mappings for Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660936(v=pandp.20).aspx#Anchor_1).